# Populate Custom Caption from Json

Tags: json, datatable, datatables

How can i populate caption of the table with the hospitallName & Date supplied in the json data?

** expected output is added here **

[image]
Json :

```
{
"sEcho":2,
"iTotalRecords":243,
"iTotalDisplayRecords":243,
"aaData":[
[
"Mark Zuckerberg",
"USA",
"Feb 14, 1943"
],
[
"John Mathew",
"UK",
"Feb 14, 1943"
],
[
"John Mathew",
"USA",
"Feb 14, 1943"
]
],
"Date":"Aug 01, 2016 - Aug 05, 2016",
"hospitallName":"Apollo Hospital Center"
}
```

--

on my server side,i am calling like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    oTable = $('#report').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bProcessing":true,
        "bFilter":true,
         "oLanguage": {
              "sProcessing": "Please wait..."
         },
        "sAjaxSource": "myDataTableAction.action",
        "aaSorting": [],

    });
    $('td.options span').hide();

    $('<caption/>').html('<h2 style="text-align: center;background-color:#f9b660 !important ; line-height: 45px;">Have to show hosital Name & Date here</h2>').appendTo( '#report' );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ajax` instead of `sAjaxSource` and use the `dataSrc` callback to populate the headers. You are not giving any example of layout or markup, but if you give the relevant headers an `id` you can do the following :

```
ajax: {
  url: 'myDataTableAction.action',
  dataSrc: function(json) {
    $('#date_head').text(json.Date)
    $('#hospitalName_head').text(json.hospitallName)
    return json.aaData
 }
}
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zvqdpeky/**

Comment: I' am passing "'myDataTableAction.action" to struts.xml.getting result in Json format,in this case also i can use "ajax" instead of "sAjaxSource"?

Comment: @dya, you could try it out? :) `sAjaxSource` is really just the hungarian notation name for the `ajax` shorthand (if it is a string .i.e url) or an object literal (if you need control over the AJAX request and response). So they are the same.

Comment: If i use ajax ,action is passing as null,
http://localhost:8080/Hospital/web/null?sEcho=1&iColumns=9&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10

Comment: What version of datatables are you using?

Comment: using  version 1.9.4

Comment: @dya, I had the feeling. I will recommend you upgrade to 1.10.x.  Perhaps you could do the same with for example the 1.9.x `fnServerData` method, and do something in `success` before calling the `fnCallback`, but it would be much easier just to upgrade.

Comment: @ david,after upgrading to 10.1.12,   `$("#report").DataTable().draw()`  function is not refreshing datatable..is this correct method for doing refresh?

Comment: hey @dya, see [**table.ajax.reload()**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) ...

Comment: I already tried with this code `var table = $("#report").DataTable();
table.ajax.reload();`,I'm getting "Please Wait" message which i given in  `"language"` field

Comment: @dye, unfortunetely I am not a telepath :) Really hard for me to debug code I cannot see, I could guess but it will only be guesses - there could be 117 reasons.

Comment: .@david , no problem,I will try to solve this..whatever i posted here is resolved with new issue :-)..thanks for ur help